# Connect to specific IP address with httr

Tags: r, ip-address, host, httr, hosts-file

I'm trying to access a website from a specific server/IP-address with R. The server is added to my Windows hosts-file like this:

IPadress domainname.ext

I can access the website with a browser (using basic authorization with username & password). But I can't access the website using R:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

url <- 'my URL'
loginAuth <- 'user login'
loginPass <- 'user password'

getdata <- GET(url, authenticate(loginAuth, loginPass, type = "basic"))
```

The reponse is a 502 status: "The requested URL could not be retrieved". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Write `url`, `loginAuth `, and `loginPass ` without `<` and `>`.

Comment: @SaurabhChauhan thx, done

Comment: @SaurabhChauhan Oh sorry, misunderstanding, I only removed the '<' and '>' from my question. It doesn't solve the problem, I didn't use these characters in the 'real' script

Comment: If still problem exists then update the question with error.

Comment: A 502 error should mean "Bad Gateway". What do you get if you leave off the authentication? What if you get the username and password wrong? What if you request a known non-existent URL on that server? Can you access a URL on the same server that doesn't need authetication?

Comment: @Spacedman I've tried all that: the GET function without authorization parameter, wrong username / password / URL: same 502 response every time. The server doesn't have other URL's, just one

Comment: does your organization use a proxy server?

Comment: @hrbrmstr yes it does. Does that interfere with things?

Comment: Yep. (`use_proxy()` docs) — https://rdrr.io/cran/httr/man/use_proxy.html. Add `verbose()` as a paramter to the `GET()` call _or_ surround the entire `GET()` call with `with_verbose()` (i.e. `with_verbose(GET(…))` to see debug-level info of what's going on to triage better (**don't** post that info here w/o reviewing it first and sanitizing it since it could leak info you don't want leaked).

Comment: @hrbrmstr thanks, I used verbose(). After some tries and 407 statuses, the connection seems to be made (<- HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
<- Proxy-Connection: close), but then the GET request to the specified path (GET /path/to/destination HTTP/1.1) with basic authorization fails.